# get data from 3 different tables in mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 3 tables in mysql with

```
theatredet(theatid,theatname,locid)
location(locid,locname)
screendet(scname,theatid,seats avail)
```

1. I want to get full table value from theatredet,
2. Need to get locname from second table on the basis of locid
3. Need to get seats avail,scname from third table basis of theatid

How can i possible in single query using c#

Comment: Can you please provide us the code you've tried and what you already have? Without any code we're not able to help you properly.

Comment: @Roman:iam not tried yet?i need the codes..

Comment: Well, please note that StackOverflow is no place to ask for codes which you *don't have*. It is to ask for help if you have any questions or problems *depending on your code*.

Comment: The codes?  Sorry they are _top secret_ so as to prevent unauthorised missile launch

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
Select td.*, l.locname, sd.seats_avail, sd.scname 
From theatredet td, location l, screendet sd
WHERE l.locid = 1 AND sd.theatid = 1
```

You can replace 1 with your number as you wanted to use as your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQl Inner Join.

Select theatredet.*,location.locname,screendet.scname,screendet.seats avail from theatredet inner join location on theatredet.locid=location.locid inner join screendet on screendet.theatid=theatredet.theatid

Answer (score 0):

This is the sql statement:

```
Select theatredet.*, locname, avail, scname
From theatredet 
Inner Join location ON location.locid = theatredet.locid
Inner Join screendet ON screendet.theatid = theatredet.theatid;
```

But you need to bind the MySql Connector to your project. take a look at this: [MySql Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)
And here is how you can use the Connector in C#: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)